# how to move multiple documents from one to another list in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, powershell, copy-and-paste, open-with-explorer, move

Can any one give me an example,how we can move the documents from 1 list to another list and also from site collection1 list to another site collection2 list.

Please help on this.

Comment: You can open in explorer and then drag and drop

Answer (score 3):

Here is a script which copies documents across site collection

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rcormier/archive/2012/11/16/how-to-copy-sharepoint-documents-between-site-collections-using-powershell.aspx

```
$ver = $host | select version
if($Ver.version.major -gt 1) {$Host.Runspace.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread"}
if(!(Get-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ea 0))
{
Write-Progress -Activity "Loading Modules" -Status "Loading Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
}

##
#Set Static Variables
##


#SourceWebURL is the URL of the web which contains the source list
$SourceWebURL = "http://sharepoint.rcormier.local"

#SoureLibraryTitle is the title of the Source Library where documents reside
$SourceLibraryTitle = "Shared Documents"

#DestinationWebURL is the URL of the web in which you want to transfer your documents
$DestinationWebURL = "http://sharepoint.rcormier.local/sites/sts_0"

#DestinationLibraryTitle is the title of the destionation library in which you want to store your files
$DestinationLibraryTitle = "Shared Documents"

##
#Begin Script
##

#Retrieve the source web, using the parameter provided
$sWeb = Get-SPWeb $SourceWebURL

#Retrieve the source list using the parameter provided
$sList = $sWeb.Lists | ? {$_.Title -eq $SourceLibraryTitle}

#Retrieve the destination web using the parameter provided
$dWeb = Get-SPWeb $DestinationWebURL

#Retrieve the source list using the parameter provided
$dList = $dWeb.Lists | ? {$_.title -like $DestinationLibraryTitle}

#Retrieve all folders in the source list.  This used to maintain the folder structure in source and destination libraries.  This excludes the root folder
$AllFolders = $sList.Folders

#Retrieve the root folder in the source list.
$RootFolder = $sList.RootFolder

#Return all files that exist directly in the root of the library
$RootItems = $RootFolder.files

#Loop through each of the documents discovered in the root of the library and perform some action
foreach($RootItem in $RootItems)
{
    #Get the Binary Stream of the referenced file, such that we can create the same file in the destination environment
    $sBytes = $RootItem.OpenBinary()

    #Create A New file using the name and binary stream from the original document, assign it to a variable.  This variable will later be called when setting properties
    $dFile = $dList.RootFolder.Files.Add($RootItem.Name, $sBytes, $true)

    #Return all fields for the source item which are not read-only
    $AllFields = $RootItem.Item.Fields | ? {!($_.sealed)}

    #Loop through all of the fields returned and perform some action
    foreach($Field in $AllFields)
    {
        #If the source item has a property that matches the name of the field perform some action
        if($RootItem.Properties[$Field.Title])
        {
            #If the destination file does not contain the same property as the source item perform some action.
            if(!($dFile.Properties[$Field.title]))
            {
                #Add a property to the file matching title and value of the same field in the original item
                $dFile.AddProperty($Field.Title, $RootItem.Properties[$Field.Title])
            }
            else
            {
                #If the property already exists, set the value on the destination item to the same value as it was in the source item.
                $dFile.Properties[$Field.Title] = $RootItem.Properties[$Field.Title]
            }

        }
    }
    #Commit the changes by updating the destination file.
    $dFile.Update()
}

#loop through all folders which are not the root folder
foreach($Folder in $AllFolders)
{
    #Since we're looping quite a bit and re-building the ParentFolderURL, make sure it doesn't exist every time we switch folders
    Remove-Variable ParentFolderURL

    #Since we're looping through sections of the folder URL, we need something to start at zero and increment as we loop through sections of the Folder URL
    $i = 0

    #Break the Folder URL up into sections, separated by "/"
    $FolderURL = $Folder.url.Split("/")

    #Perform a variable number of actions against the Folder URL based on the number of sections in FolderURL
    while($i -lt ($FolderURL.count-1))
    {
    #Keep apending the Folder section in order to build the parent folder URL
    $ParentFolderURL = "$ParentFolderURL/" + $FolderURL[$i]

    #Increment the I variable in order to move forward through the folder structure
    $i++
    }

    $CurrentFolder = $dList.Folders | ? {$_.url -eq $ParentFolderURL.substring(1)}
    #If the destination list does not contain a folder with the same name, create it
    if(!($CurrentFolder.Folders | ? {$_.name -eq $Folder.Name}))
    {
        #Create a Folder in the destination library with the same name as it had in the source library, in the same relative location
        $NewFolder = $dlist.Folders.Add(("$DestinationWebURL" + $ParentFolderURL), [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileSystemObjectType]::Folder, $Folder.name)

        #Finalize creating the folder by calling update
        $NewFolder.update()
    }
    else
    {
        #If the folder already exists, retrieve the folder where the file will be created
        $NewFolder = $dList.Folders | ? {$_.name -eq $Folder.Name}
    }

    #Return all files from the source list.  we will use this later to perform updates on items
    $AllFiles = $sList.Items

    #Return all items from the current folder
    $sItems = $Folder.folder.Files

    #If the folder we're currently in has more than zero objects, perform some actions.
    if($Folder.Folder.Files.count -gt 0)
    {
        #Perform some actions against each object in the current folder
        foreach($item in $sItems)
        {
            #Get the relative URL from the current item            
            $Relative = ($Item.ServerRelativeUrl).substring(1)

            #Based on the relative path of the current item, retrieve the file from the site
            $TargetItem = $AllFiles | ? {$_.URL -eq $Relative}

            #Retrieve the binary stream of the current file
            $sBytes = $TargetItem.File.OpenBinary()

            #Create a file in destination library, same relative folder, using the current file's name and binary stream
            $dFile = $Newfolder.Folder.Files.Add($TargetItem.Name, $sBytes, $true)

            #Return all fields for the source item which are not read-
            $AllFields = $TargetItem.Fields | ? {!($_.sealed)}

            #Loop through all of the fields returned and perform some action
            foreach($Field in $AllFields)
            {
                #If the destination file does not contain the same property as the source item perform some action.
                if($TargetItem.Properties[$Field.Title])
                {
                    #If the destination file does not contain the same property as the source item perform some action.
                    if(!($dFile.Properties[$Field.title]))
                    {
                        #Add a property to the file matching title and value of the same field in the original item
                        $dFile.AddProperty($Field.Title, $TargetItem.Properties[$Field.Title])
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        #If the property already exists, set the value on the destination item to the same value as it was in the source item.
                        $dFile.Properties[$Field.Title] = $TargetItem.Properties[$Field.Title]
                    }

                }
            }
            #Commit the changes by updating the destination file.
            $dFile.Update()
                    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well the simplest and easiest solution would be to go to Computer > Add Network Location and copy-paste the address of the List (address can be found in the List's Settings).

[image]

Reapeat for the other list as well. Now you have two folder shortcuts pointing to the contents of each list, on your SP Server. From then on it's simple cut and paste from one folder to the other. I find this the easiest way to move documents around SP Libraries or to add a large number of documents in a library at once. Hope this helps!